# Multiple Choice/Fill-In-The-Blank Shell Script

Tags: shell

How do you write a shell script with multiple choice answers and fill-in-the-blank answers? I have tried Googling this, but I didn't come up with anything. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: bash, I think. I'm on OS X, so I'm pretty sure that's what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `select` command: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs